# How can I Echoing Data After Checking For Existence in PHP Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I don't have anything store on my user phone field at the moment.

`<li><i class="md md-phone"></i>  {{ $user->phone or 'No Phone' }} </li>`

So this line should print out `No Phone`.

[image]

But instead it print out as blank. I'm confuse. What did I do wrong /forgot ?

Is it because my `$user->phone` is exist, but it's `value is = NULL` ?

Comment: {{ $user->phone ?: "no phone" }} should work

Comment: @oBo is correct. And the reason, as you guessed, is that the value is set to something - even though it happens to be null.

Comment: @oBo : It works. How do you know that ? Why you don't use the word `or` ?

Comment: or ? ive never heard of that.. see {{ $user->phone ?: "no phone" }} translates to if($user->phone){echo $user->phone;}else{echo "no phone";}

You can also set another value than $user->phone by defining it after the question mark, for example {{ $user->phone ? "this works too" : "no phone" }}

Comment: Cool. Thanks. `or` is just something that Laravel offer right out of the box.

Comment: Ah i see. Thanks for the tip!, so the "or" syntax corresponds to {{ isset($user->phone) ? $user->phone : "no phone }}

And since its set but the value is null, it doesnt work

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ $var or 'No Phone' }}` === `{{ isset($var)? $var : 'No Phone' }}`

Because `$user->phone` is defined you should use this: `{{ $user->phone? $user->phone : 'No Phone' }}`

Or, you can go nice Laravel way and create your own [directive for Blade templates](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-blade) and use it like this: `@var($user->phone, 'No phone')`

Comment: I feel that @oBo solution is a little shorter `{{ $user->phone ?: "no phone" }}`